# The import com.google.firebase.messaging cannot be resolved in MyFirebaseMessagingService.java

Tags: android, eclipse, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I get the following error:

> The import com.google.firebase.messaging cannot be resolved in
>   MyFirebaseMessagingService.java

And I get other errors such as:

- `FirebaseMessagingService` cannot be resolved to a type
- `RemoteMessage` cannot be resolved to a type
- The constructor `Intent(MyFirebaseMessagingService, Class<MainActivity>)` is     undefined
- The method `getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int)` in the type `PendingIntent` is not applicable for the arguments `(MyFirebaseMessagingService, int, Intent, int)`
- The constructor `NotificationCompat.Builder(MyFirebaseMessagingService)` is undefined
- The method `getSystemService(String)` is undefined for the type `MyFirebaseMessagingService`

How should I solve these problems in **MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**?

I get the codes from https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java

Comment: How do you compile it ? Have you tried with gradle ?

Comment: @JFPicard I am using eclipse not android studio. So far i have not touched my build.gradle file

Comment: There is a gradlew.bat in the project. The file will probably help you to download the depencies.

Comment: show your code here

Comment: If possible, migrate to Android Studio because Eclipse is officially deprecated by Google for Android development. I use Android Studio, FCM works for me and this is what I have in my build.gradle file in the section for dependencies: `compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.0"`